# Match by ID and closest date in two files then return the column number

Tags: excel

Sheet 1 Column:

ID, Visit#, VisitDate

Sheet 2 data:

ID, Visit1Date, Visit2Date, Visit3Date, etc.

Sheet 1 is missing Visit#s for all IDs, but DOES have VisitDate.
I need to pull the visit# from sheet 2 into sheet 1. So, I need to pull the visit number (column #) from sheet 2 based on the match visit date.

I'm having a real hard time even describing what I need here, so please feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MATCH(C2,INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$DD,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),0),0)-1
```

This will look for an exact match on the dates.  If that is not what is wanted then remove the last `,0` from the equation and it will return the column where the date is less than but not greater than the next column:

```
=MATCH(C2,INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$DD,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),0))-1
```

[image]

Sheet2 for reference:

[image]

Comment: Life saver! Thank you!

Comment: I have another challenge. What if I want to pull the date? 

Example: In the top sheet in your answer, I have the Visit# and I want to pull the visit DATE from the second sheet based on the visit# in the column heading?

Comment: Use a vlookup with the ID as the first criterion anb visit number as the third. If you can't make it work put it in another question. I am away from my desk for the next little while and someone may be able to get a better answer quicker.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help so far! Really apprecaite it

Comment: What does $DD mean? Is that column DD?

Comment: Yes it is. I just choose a large column.